# Pointing to index.html in Django

Tags: python, django

I just updated to a newer version of django and now having difficulties pointing to my index.html file

This is the structure of my project

```
gradMVPV1
--> .idea
--> catalog
    views
    models
    apps
    ....
--> gradMVPV1
    settings
    urls
    wsgi
    ....
--> templates
---->index.html
db.sqlite3
manage.py
```

This is my settings.py file

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/templates')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, "index"),
]
```

and views

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, "index.html")
```

this is my error message

```
 ValueError at /
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
Request Method:
GET
Request URL:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:
2.2.7
Exception Type:
ValueError
Exception Value:
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
Exception Location:
C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in resolve, line 348
Python Executable:
C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\python.exe
Python Version:
3.7.4
```

Comment: Can you post full traceback of error you get?

Comment: Try removing the / from /templates. i.e. TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')

Comment: probably need `name` --> `path('', views.index, name="index")`

Comment: I think it has something to do with contents of your template, because I can't see anything that would call resolve function from what you posted. I think it would be helpful to see template content as well

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could provide your full template settings. It is configured as TEMPLATES = [{All your settings in here}]

Comment: @Rakesh is most probably right, try it!

Comment: Thanks...added name= 'index' and removed the / from templates works now

Comment: It's windows isn't it?

Comment: @MichaelStachura yeah

Answer (score 0):

Fix `path('', views.index, "index"),]`  into 
`path('', views.index,  name = "index"),]`